# Layout - the height of the inside panel will not be affected

Tags: java, swing

Hi I am fairly new to Java. I have JPanel which added other JPanel. The number of the inside JPanel is depend on the list. If the list is delete or add then I remove all inside JPanel and add JPanel according  updated list. The inside panel will have different height depend of the data of the list. My problem is the height of the inside panel will change to fit the outside JPanel because of the total amount of inside panel change. I want the height of the inside panel will not be affected when I delete or add the new inside JPanel. I use BoxLayout for the outside panel.  Would someone tell me how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

There is the code I add the inside JPanel into the outsider JPanel

```
    jpListCommentPane=new JPanel();   
    jpListCommentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpListCommentPane,  
 BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


      //sortPage

     Component[] components = jpListCommentPane.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            jpListCommentPane.remove(component);                
            jpListCommentPane.repaint();
        }

      sortComment= lstComment;
     Collections.sort(sortComment,CommentItem.sortPage);
     for(CommentItem comm: sortComment){
         DivCommentJPane d=new DivCommentJPane(comm, this);
         jpListCommentPane.add(d);

     }  


     jpListCommentPane.revalidate();
```

There is the screen shot for comparison:
    [image]

Comment: A little off topic, but why don't you use a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) ? I think (really not sure) `JList` with custom cell renderer should to trick

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.